# IWebBrowser2 facebook login

Tags: facebook, visual-c++, authentication, webbrowser-control, win32ole

I'm working on a windows based application in C++ that requires facebook login. I'm using using Ole Embedding/ActiveX control with the CLSID_WebBrowser component (IWebBrowser2) to do the authentication.

This works pretty well in so far as I create a window, embed the activeX web browser control, and then I direct it to the facebook login with an 'authorization url', such as...

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=xxxx&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&scope=basic_info

xxx is set to our app id.

This works, and you can login. The problem is if I quit and restart the app, even if I've selected 'keep me logged in' in the web page, I will generally have to retype in my password.

I say generally, because if I don't use the facebook auth url above, and say go to www.facebook.com, within my active x control and log in - it will remember that I'm logged in, and I don't have to type in password if I shutdown and restart the app.

As another side detail all of this is separate from the behavior of just running IE. If I run IE and login - it has no effect on the login inside of the app. And it's not something that is unique to my implementation of ActiveX control embedding. If I run the JUCE library demo - which has a web browser active X component, it has the same behavior as with mine. That is...

1) I can login via https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize - but if I restart the demo, it won't remember my previous login
2) If I login via www.facebook.com then it does remember I've logged in
  + Actually a login like this in JUCE will allow me to login without a password from my app
3) Login from IE has no effect

It's tedious to have to login every time, and seems like incorrect behavior to have to do it if you select 'remain logged in'. It does not appear that it's a problem with the ActiveX control saving session state - as session state is maintained when I use the www.facebook.com login. It may be worth saying - I can't use www.facebook.com login, because it doesn't return the information that the app requires to work, that's what the authorize style url is all about.

The implication seems to be that facebook is doing something different in these scenarios - it's not storing the login information if you use the authorization url.

So my question is how to fix the problem - such that 'remain logged in' will remain logged for an application authentication through the authorization url?

I guess as a work around, you could store the authorization token in the app, and try and see it that token is valid at startup perhaps. I'm not sure that's the 'right' way to do it. 
Also note - my original implementation used Ole Automation (effectively my app controlled a separate IE process), and it had none of these problems. BUT unfortunately with IE 11, Ole Automation seems to have been broken.

Thank you for your time and wisdom.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find away to honor 'keep me logged in' within facebook. Instead, if a user logs in I store the authorization token encrypted in a file. If they restart the application, it will attempt to login using the stored auth token. If it fails, a standard login sequence is pursed. This is equivalent to acting as if 'keep me logged in' is always set, which isn't right, but is better from a usability point of view than the opposite.

It may potentially be possible to lookup the 'keep me logged in' element from the DOM of the webpage, and see what it is set to. This seems kinda fragile.

I remain open to suggestions on, how to 'do this properly'.

Comment: Hello Can you please share the code for facebook login. I am also trying to login with facebook in juce which also use the c++ code.